# GCP's SSH terminal not working after stopping and starting vm instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, spring-cloud-gcp

I am using gcp vm machine instance N1-standard 8V-30GB and N1-standard 4V-15GB

- os-Debian
- version - Debian GNU/Linux 10(buster)

this issue i am facing from last 1 month.
**public access permission denied** is one of message i am seeing while trying to access from cloud shell
I had run `command chmod 777 <home directory>` earlier.

Comment: What are the file? How do you try to access to file through Cloud Shell? What command do you use?

Comment: this command from gcp documentation
> gcloud compute instances start example-instance --zone=us-central1-a

Comment: Ok, Now your VM is started. Which command do you use then to log into the VM?

Comment: I usually do this way
**steps**
1- GCP 2-compute Engine
3-VM instances 
4-if vm is running then i will click on drop down of SSH and select open in browser window.
window will pop up and try to connect but can not make connection.

Comment: Have you looked through the serial console log (`GCP Console => Compute Engine => VM instances => your_instance => Serial port 1 (console)`)? Are there any errors related to SSH?

Comment: Did you only change the permissions on your home directory or did you run this command recursively? If recursively, you have broken the security for the `~/.ssh` folder and you will not be able to login. Mount the disk on another instance to repair. You can also take a snapshot, mount on another instance, repair and then create a new instance from the repaired disk.

Comment: @mebius99
i checked logs but there is no such error..

Comment: @JohnHanley
yes i ran command recursively. now to repair vm instance i have created snapshot, mount on another instance but i didn't find way to repair. there is reset option available.
how to repair ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your steps and was able to solve this issue.

Please have a look at my steps below:

1. [create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) VM instances:

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=e2-medium --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20200701 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud
gcloud compute instances create instance-2 --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=e2-medium --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20200701 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud
```

2. [change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) permissions recursively on my home directory at the VM instance `instance-1`:

```
instance-1:~$ chmod -R 777 ~
instance-1:~$ ls -la
...
drwxrwxrwx 2 username username 4096 Jul 15 07:50 .ssh
```

3. [create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/snapshot) snapshot of the VM instance `instance-1` boot disk:

```
gcloud compute disks snapshot instance-1 --snapshot-names instance-1-snapshot --zone=europe-west3-a
```

4. [create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/create) a new disk with the snapshot:

```
gcloud compute disks create instance-1-snapshot-disk --zone=europe-west3-a --source-snapshot=instance-1-snapshot
```

5. [attach](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) created disk `instance-1-snapshot-disk` to the VM instance `instance-2`:

```
instance-2:~$ ls -l /dev/ | grep sd
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,     0 Jul 15 07:39 sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,     1 Jul 15 07:39 sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,    14 Jul 15 07:39 sda14
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,    15 Jul 15 07:39 sda15
instance-2:~$ mount | grep sda
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda15 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

then

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk instance-2 --disk=instance-1-snapshot-disk --zone=europe-west3-a
```

after that

```
instance-2:~$ ls -l /dev/ | grep sd
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,     0 Jul 15 07:39 sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,     1 Jul 15 07:39 sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,    14 Jul 15 07:39 sda14
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,    15 Jul 15 07:39 sda15
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,    16 Jul 15 08:04 sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,    17 Jul 15 08:04 sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,    30 Jul 15 08:04 sdb14
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,    31 Jul 15 08:04 sdb15
instance-2:~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/instance-1-snapshot-disk
instance-2:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/instance-1-snapshot-disk
instance-2:~$ ls -la /mnt/instance-1-snapshot-disk
total 104
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root  4096 Jul 15 07:56 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jul 15 08:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:14 bin
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:19 boot
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:11 dev
drwxr-xr-x 93 root root  4096 Jul 15 07:55 etc
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Jul 15 07:50 home
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    30 Jul  1 19:18 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-1030-gcp
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    30 Jul  1 19:18 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-1030-gcp
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:17 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:01 lib64
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Jul  1 19:13 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:01 media
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:01 mnt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:01 opt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 24  2018 proc
drwx------  3 root root  4096 Jul 15 07:36 root
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:19 run
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:17 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 Jul 15 07:36 snap
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:01 srv
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 24  2018 sys
drwxrwxrwt  7 root root  4096 Jul 15 07:56 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:01 usr
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root  4096 Jul  1 19:12 var
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    27 Jul  1 19:18 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-1030-gcp
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    27 Jul  1 19:18 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-1030-gcp
```

6. change permissions:

   - `.ssh` directory: 700 `drwx------`
   - public key (`.pub` file): 644 `-rw-r--r--`
   - private key (`id_rsa`): 600 `-rw-------`
   - lastly your home directory should not be writeable by the group or others: 755 `drwxr-xr-x`

```
instance-2:~$ chmod -R 755 /mnt/instance-1-snapshot-disk/home/username/
instance-2:~$ chmod -R 700 /mnt/instance-1-snapshot-disk/home/username/.ssh/
instance-2:~$ chmod 644 /mnt/instance-1-snapshot-disk/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

unmount the disk when you finish:

```
instance-2:~$ sudo umount /mnt/instance-1-snapshot-disk/
```

7. [detach](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/detach-disk) disk `instance-1-snapshot-disk` from the VM instance `instance-2`:

```
gcloud compute instances detach-disk instance-2 --disk=instance-1-snapshot-disk --zone=europe-west3-a
```

8. [create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) a new instance from the repaired disk:

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-3 --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=e2-medium --disk=name=instance-1-snapshot-disk
```

9. check SSH connection to at the VM instance `instance-1`.

In addition, please have a look at the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) section [Inspect the VM instance without shutting it down](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#inspect_vm) to find more details.

Comment: thanks for your efforts.
I follow all steps, all of them ran correctly. now after this i restart instance-1 but then i am not able to connect SSH of instance-1 again.
same thing happen for all the other users including owner of project.
I have posted que below to attach screenshot.

Comment: Do you use Cloud IAP? Have you tried to connect via web Console? Does your instance has an external IP?

Comment: yes i am using  Cloud IAP and instance has external IP.
i never tried to connect via web Console. but i tried cloud shell to connect.

Comment: Is it possible to change temporary firewall rules and connect to the instance with a command `gcoud compute ssh` without using flag `--tunnel-through-iap`?

Comment: without changing firewall rules, i tried *gcloud compute ssh instance --zone=us-central1-a*  on cloud shell, and i got access to my home directory, All your suggested step worked perfectly here to access from cloud shell. thanks a lot for your time and patience !!
still no luck with ssh window, if you have some more solutions please suggest me i will try them too.

Comment: Have you tried to disable IAP for some particular VM and then connect to it via SSH?

Comment: no i never disable IAP for some particular VM. 
even not after the issue.

Comment: Okay. It looks like your issue with SSH was solved (at least you have access from Cloud Shell). I'd recommend you to post another question about your issue with IAP. Please upvote my answer if it was helpful for you.

Comment: yes thanks, at least i am able to access vai cloud shell.  sure i will post that.

Answer (score 0):

From owner's account i tried to access instance-1 but owner is also not able to connect to the instance-1.

*owner of project got this pop-up on ssh window*
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2fzC.jpg

**I observe that in fresh new created instance if i add add some file like git clone repo, after that if i restart it then i am able to connect SSH again.**